# Australians and SR1

Tags: australian-english

This [Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SR1) in question.

Do Australians still use the Spelling Reform 1 (SR1) officially or unofficially?

> It calls for the short /ɛ/ sound (as in bet) to always be spelt with E.

said→sed, jeopardy→jepardy, bury→bery, etc.

Comment: "Still use"? Realistically, did they *ever*?

Comment: Agreed, the Wikipedia article is questionable. I've lived in Australia for 32 years and never seen SR1 in use.

Comment: SR1 was 'championed' by the *Australian Teachers' Federation*, which, depending on your viewpoint either became defunct or was merged into the *Australian Teachers Union* in 1991. Back in 1975 it did *ask* the government to endorse small-scale trials of SR1, but I doubt anything like that ever actually took place.

Comment: Uh, bury doesn't have a short e sound.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So they didn't teach it in school?

Comment: @Andrew: I can't say for certain, but be realistic - how do you think the parents of any chosen 'trial' school would feel? It just wouldn't get off the ground, I feel.

Comment: Voting to close on the grounds there's nothing much to say about this in an EL&U context.

Comment: The trouble with spelling that follows pronunciation is that pronunciation varies from place to place.

Comment: @Joe Blow: if you vandalize it someone will change it back. If you make good edits they will stay. I made a lot and they were never reversed. Anyway, staying on-topic, I don't see any evidence whatsoever on that page that says Australians use the SR1 spelling reform. It just says that SR1 **had some success** in Australia and quotes a 25 year old book...

Comment: By the way, just to let all folks know, I have edited the Wikipedia page so that it is in keeping with the Australian Trade Unions Archives. Cheers

Comment: Having read the Wikipedia article after spending 45 years as an Australian and not recalling ever hearing of *SR1* before today, I can say I've never seen such a "general interest paperback" - and I spend a lot of time in seconhand bookshops. The one thing that did ring true was the spelling ***thru*** which was common enough to annoy me when I was growing up in the '70s and '80s. I recall noting on a trip to the US at the time that it was less common over there even though I and others had disliked it for being "too American".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I live in Australia and I should know. No, it was never in wide usage, because I have lived here quite some time, and I have never seen it.

> This simple spelling reform has been adopted widely by Australians.

Really? I think it's because Wikipedia can be edited simply just by anyone, not too much credence should be placed on some of its articles. Personally, "adopted widely" is a "figment of imagination" to me, and I have *never* seen it, unless it was by someone illiterate.

The Australian Teachers' Federation might have adopted this policy, but you can see by this [link](http://www.atua.org.au/biogs/ALE0253b.htm) that they ceased to exist in 1987.

So, I hope that answers your question.

Comment: As I said in the other comment, that is a quote from a 1985 book...

Comment: By the way, just to let all folks know, I have edited the Wikipedia page so that it is in keeping with the Australian Trade Unions Archives. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Mate, the article is simply rubbish.

Note that the first paragraph of the article contains the sentence:

> It had some success in Australia...

It's simply wrong, and silly. Ask any Aussie. As Ham already pointed out, the next sentence is also at best misleading.